# Formal definition for "no limits"

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation, definition

We all know the formal definition of limit. I'm trying to write a formal definition for "no limits". For context, this is for a very stupid tattoo. Don't drink and bet with tattoo artists, friends.

Here are my four options. Options 1/2 and 3/4 are the same aside from substitution s.t. for colons. Before I get this permanently inked on me with flaming hearts and daggers, I want to get some other eyes on it. Are there any mistakes? Is there a better definition? Which of these do you think is the most accurate?

Option 1:
\[
\forall x_0 \in \mathbb R; \;
\exists \epsilon > 0:
\Big \lvert f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to x_o} f(x) \Big \rvert < \epsilon \;
\land \;
\not\exists \delta > 0: \Big | x - x_0 \Big | < \delta
\]

Option 2:
\[
\forall x_0 \in \mathbb R; \;
\exists \epsilon > 0 \text{ s.t. }
\Big \lvert f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to x_o} f(x) \Big \rvert < \epsilon \;
\land \;
\not\exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. } \Big | x - x_0 \Big | < \delta
\]

Option 3:
\[
\forall x_0 \in \mathbb R; \;
\forall \epsilon > 0; \;
\Big \lvert f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to x_o} f(x) \Big \rvert < \epsilon
\not \implies
\exists \delta > 0: \Big | x - x_0 \Big | < \delta
\]

Option 4:
\[
\forall x_0 \in \mathbb R; \;
\forall \epsilon > 0; \;
\Big \lvert f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to x_o} f(x) \Big \rvert < \epsilon
\not \implies
\exists \delta > 0 \text{ s.t. }  \Big | x - x_0 \Big | < \delta
\]

(Note, I normally use centernot for does not imply but MathJax doesn't support it)

Comment: I guess I would do $\liminf_{x \to x_0} f(x) < \limsup_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ and give the artist a break :-).

Comment: What do you mean with "no limits"? That the absolute value tends to infinity?

Comment: Tattoo Artist is likely to mix up $\epsilon$ with $e$ & $\delta$ with $8$ & $x_0$ with $x0$ ETC. Making Corrections will be Difficult. Stick with using $\infty$ to indicate that there are no limits.

Comment: The liminf and limsup version works better too because it's more general whilst still concise: it handles the case of divergent behaviour (to $\pm\infty$) as well as the oscillatory cases

Comment: ooh, the liming/limsup version is better but less ridiculous. But I think I might go with that. Thanks!